# SQLite - How to get query's result depending linked tables?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I've the following tables :

> *place_table*
>
> **id** | **name**

---

> *spot_table*
>
> **id** | **name** | **place_id**

I want to get all the places which has at least one spot.

How is it possible to do this with an SQLite query ? (I'm working on an Android project)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below SQLite Query

```
 SELECT * FROM place_table WHERE id IN (SELECT place_id FROM spot_table)
```